# What does symmetry of equations mean?

Tags: calculus

This is from Munkres'*Analysis on Manifolds*.

The context is partial derivatives. Why can we go from one equation to the other because of symmetry? What symmetry.

We are trying to prove $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$[image]

Also shouldn’t the red part be $A——>R$ not $R^2$?

Edit for comments:

First thank you for helping as I am in quarantine and can’t get much help other than this site.

I don’t really get what you mean by switching $x_1$ and $x_2$. For example, A=$f(x_1,x_2)=3x_1^2 +2x_2^2$ Then by switching do you mean B=$f(x_2,x_1)=3x_1^2+2x_2^2$? If so, I get how if $p=(p_1,p_2)$ satisfies A for the equation then $q=(p_2,p_1)$ satisfies B but aren’t B and A different functions? And how do I know $q$ is actually in our rectangle. For instance if our rectangle is $(100+h)$ $(100+k)$ wouldn’t switching change $h$ and $k$ thus changing our rectangle? I know this is probably what you mean. I would be grateful if you could be more specific as what you mean by changing $x_1,x_2$ by giving an example or being more specific as I am totally lost (I get the whole proof in the book but this little detail and I just don’t get this minor detail)

Comment: Yes, it should be $f: A \subset \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was going crazy

Comment: Also, for the "symmetry" part, I don't immediately see any symmetry, but the proof of the second equation is very very similar to the proof of the first equation. You just have to modify the phrasing of the argument slightly. (this isn't meant to say there is no symmetry, just that you shouldn't get hung up on this small detail, and rather should focus on the rest of the proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry is the interchange of $x_1$ and $x_2$, which transforms the two equations into each other.

As has already been stated in the comments, you’re right about the range of $f$ being $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks but wouldn’t changing $x_1$ and $x_2$ change $Q$ (our rectangle)? Sorry I tried to use a diagram to see it but just couldn’t.

Comment: What I mean is that how does switching the variables not effect the properties of the function/how it makes sense.

Comment: @Dhdh: I'm not sure what you mean. Let's make it more concrete: What did you get when you interchanged $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the first equation? Then we can see what went wrong and why you didn't get the second equation.

Comment: I edited my original answer but I know I am probably wrong. Please help me understand.